# Why doesn't WSDL 2.0 support operator oveloading

Tags: wsdl-2.0

I was wondering why WSDL 2.0 does not support operator overloading, in the sense that I wonder  what it stands to gain from excluding this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because operations are distinguished by the IRIs:
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/#frag-ids
You can't define overloaded operations maintaining the same IRI.
Probably there could be problems in some languages mappings also...